# Obtener todos los registros de una tabla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quiero obtener todos los "Contactos" que tengo en una tabla de `sql`, lo cual utilizo `entity framework` para hacer las consultas y mostrar esa info en un `select` que tengo en una vista.

```
var contactos = db.Contactos.Where(x => x.ContactoId == Id & x.Activo == true).ToList();
var lista = new SelectList(contactos);
ViewBag.ContactoId = lista;
```

```
@Html.DropDownList("ContactoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Estoy utilizando este código pero me devuelve `false` en vez de los nombres de los contactos que quiero obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142774/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-luis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la conversación en la sala de chat, se necesitó del siguiente código para tener la lista de nombres:

```
db.Contactos.Where(x => x.Activo == true)
            .Select(x => x.Nombre)
            .ToList();
```